# python: how to convert list of tuples to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have list of **tuples (x,y coordinates)** converted to a string and written in a file. When I read line from file, my list looks like this:

```
[(341, 115), (174, 227), (457, 308)]
```

how do I convert this kind of **list to numpy array**? end result should look like this:

```
[[341 115]
 [174 227]
 [457 308]]
```

Comment: `np.array("[(341, 115), (174, 227), (457, 308)]")` ?

Comment: np.array(literal_eval("[(341, 115), (174, 227), (457, 308)]")) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `numpy`:

```
lst = [(341, 115), (174, 227), (457, 308)]

import numpy as np
print(np.array(lst))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[341 115]
 [174 227]
 [457 308]]
```

Using `list comprehension`:

```
print([list(lst) for lst in lst])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[341, 115], [174, 227], [457, 308]]
```

**EDIT**:

If it is a string which it does not look like in the code pasted in the question:

```
lst = "[(341, 115), (174, 227), (457, 308)]"
```

Then:

```
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval
print(np.array(literal_eval(lst)))
```

Eventually (for list comprehension):

```
print([list(lst) for lst in literal_eval(lst)])
```

Comment: `[int(x) for x in lst]` is redundant as all elements in `lst` are already of type `int`. Just use `list(lst)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the line (a string) to an actual list object, and call `numpy.array` directly on it:

```
line = "[(341, 115), (174, 227), (457, 308)]"

from ast import literal_eval
import numpy as np

np.array(literal_eval(line))
```

Output:

```
array([[341, 115],
   [174, 227],
   [457, 308]])
```